# How to reverse each word in a text file with linux commands without changing order of words

Tags: linux

There's lots of questions indicating how to reverse each word in a sentence, and I could readily do this in Python or Javascript for example, but how can I do it with Linux commands? It looks like `tac` might be an option, but seems like this would likely reverse lines as well as words, rather than just words? What other tools can do this? I literally have no idea. I know `rev` and `tac` and `awk` all seem like contenders...

So I'd like to go from:

```
cat dog sleep
pillow green blue
```

to:

```
tac god peels
wollip neerg eulb
```

**slight followup

From [this reference](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) it looks like I could use `awk` to break each field up into an array of single characters and then write a for loop to reverse manually each word in this way. This is quite awkward. Surely there's a better/more succinct way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to go from "cat dog" to "tac god"?

Comment: Considering `awk` is a Turing-complete programming language, it would definitely be capable of doing it.  You'd probably have to define a function, though.

Comment: @bbill I updated my question to clarify. I want to preserve the order of words but reverse each word.

Comment: @TrippKinetics That's an interesting bit of trivia. Clearly awk can access each word, but I don't know how to parse each word inside awk. Will keep reading up on this.

Comment: `rev` and `tac` will have trouble doing it without collapsing whitespace, I think.

Comment: The problem described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891286/awk-reverse-both-lines-and-words isn't completely identical to the one you pose, but the accepted answer should get you most of the way there.

Comment: `sed` could probably do it too, come to think of it.  I'd bet the syntax would look like line noise, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
sed -e 's/\s+/ /g' -e 's/ /\n/g' < file.txt | rev | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo
```

It collapses all the space and counts punctuation as part of "words", but it looks like it (at least mostly) works.  Hooray for `sh`!